# Finding a value of $x$ such that $\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}=\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^x \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}=\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^x \frac{1}{4}$$
After using the formula $\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)dx$ for the average value I got

$$\frac{3\ln(t)}{x-1}= \frac{\ln(t)}{x-1/4} $$
$$$$

$$\frac{\ln(t)}{x-1/4}$$ can be rewritten as $$\frac{4\ln(t)}{4x-1}$$

then when  the denominator is multiplied by $3\ln(t)$
$$$$
$$12\ln(t)-3\ln(t)$$
and crossing the other two terms produces
$$4\ln(t)*x-1=4x\ln(t)-4\ln(t)$$

To get
$$12x\ln(t)-3\ln(t)=4x\ln(t)-4\ln(t)$$
Then by adding the $-4\ln(t)$ to each side gives you
$$12x\ln(t)+\ln(t)=4x\ln(t)$$ 
$$$$
Then I solved for $x$ which gave me $x=-\frac{1}{8}$

When I checked my answer I was off by a lot. Also sorry I didn't show every step, it getting late but I want to finish studying.

Comment: what are the variables of integration?

Comment: Your first equation doesn't match your second equation. The first equation doesn't say anything about averages. And why does the second equation have both an $x$ and a $t$ in it after integrating when $t$ is just a dummy variable? Very little makes sense to me here. I suspect important context is missing from your question.

Comment: @runway44 Is this clearer to you now?

Comment: How are the first two equations related to each other? Why do you still have the $t$ variable even after you integrated? What does the average formula have to do with the first equation? | You seem to forgetting to replace $t$ with the bounds when you apply the fundamental theorem of calculus. | I suspect that either (a) the average formula has nothing to do with your problem, or (b) the original problem you were given had to do with averages in which case your first equation is wrong.

Comment: @runway44 As to your first question I got no clue, the whole question is "Find a value of x such that" and then the two functions. I guess I should get some sleep because, you're right, there shouldn't be any t's left after integration. The section the question is in has to do with the FTC part 2 with is the average value of a integral.

Comment: Does the problem itself mention averages? What book, section, problem number?

Comment: @runway44 Calculus 11th edition by Larson and Edwards, section 5.2, problem number 83

Comment: Is there a $3$ missing in a numerator in the first equation? Your second equation has a $3$ in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just compute the integrals
$$\int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t}=\log(x)$$ $$\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^x \frac{dt}{4}=\frac{1}{4} \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ lead to the equation
$$\log(x)-\frac{1}{4} \left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)=0$$ the solutions of which being given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Skipping the intermediate steps (which are well described in the linked page - have a look at example $1$ which is exactly your problem), you should end with
$$x_1=-4 W_0\left(-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt[16]{e}}\right)\approx 1.30026$$
$$x_2=-4 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt[16]{e}}\right)\approx 9.06980$$

If you cannot use Lambert function, only numerical methods would provide the result.